# Library linking using wxWidgets through Cygwin

Tags: c++, cygwin, mingw, static-libraries, wxwidgets

I have been trying to get wxWidgets working on Cygwin. So far I have had success by using a mingw compiler available through the cygwin installer.
The build seemed to work fine. The configure message I used was:
`configure --host=i686-w64-mingw32 --build=i686-pc-cygwin --enable-static --disable-shared`
After that I ran a make and make install and got no errors.

Next I grabbed an example from [a tutorial](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/overview_helloworld.html) and ran:
`i686-w64-mingw32-g++ -c -o hello_world.o hello_world.cpp CXX_FLAGS` 
`i686-w64-mingw32-g++ -o a hello_world.o CXX_FLAGS LIBS` 
where CXX_FLAGS and LIBS are generated from `wx-config -cxxflags` and `wx-config --libs`. This works fine, but when I try to run the executable I get this error:
`C:/Users/sam/Documents/cpp/wxwidgets_tutorial/a.exe: error while loading shared libraries: ?: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

The libraries I build should be static, so I'm not sure what to do with this message. Any help is greatly appreciated!

#### Some more info:

wx-config --cxxflags gives the output: 
`-I/usr/local/lib/wx/include/i686-w64-mingw32-msw-unicode-static-3.0 -I/usr/local/include/wx-3.0 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D__WXMSW__ -mthreads`

wx-config --libs give the output: 
`-L/usr/local/lib   -Wl,--subsystem,windows -mwindows /usr/local/lib/libwx_mswu_xrc-3.0-i686-w64-mingw32.a /usr/local/lib/libwx_mswu_webview-3.0-i686-w64-mingw32.a /usr/local/lib/libwx_mswu_qa-3.0-i686-w64-mingw32.a /usr/local/lib/libwx_baseu_net-3.0-i686-w64-mingw32.a /usr/local/lib/libwx_mswu_html-3.0-i686-w64-mingw32.a /usr/local/lib/libwx_mswu_adv-3.0-i686-w64-mingw32.a /usr/local/lib/libwx_mswu_core-3.0-i686-w64-mingw32.a /usr/local/lib/libwx_baseu_xml-3.0-i686-w64-mingw32.a /usr/local/lib/libwx_baseu-3.0-i686-w64-mingw32.a -lpng -ljpeg -ltiff -lexpat -lwxregexu-3.0-i686-w64-mingw32 -lz -lrpcrt4 -loleaut32 -lole32 -luuid -lwinspool -lwinmm -lshell32 -lcomctl32 -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 -lwsock32 -lgdi32`

ls /usr/local/lib: 
`libwx_baseu_net-3.0-i686-w64-mingw32.a
libwx_baseu_xml-3.0-i686-w64-mingw32.a
libwx_baseu-3.0-i686-w64-mingw32.a
libwx_mswu_adv-3.0-i686-w64-mingw32.a
libwx_mswu_aui-3.0-i686-w64-mingw32.a
libwx_mswu_core-3.0-i686-w64-mingw32.a
libwx_mswu_gl-3.0-i686-w64-mingw32.a
libwx_mswu_html-3.0-i686-w64-mingw32.a
libwx_mswu_media-3.0-i686-w64-mingw32.a
libwx_mswu_propgrid-3.0-i686-w64-mingw32.a
libwx_mswu_qa-3.0-i686-w64-mingw32.a
libwx_mswu_ribbon-3.0-i686-w64-mingw32.a
libwx_mswu_richtext-3.0-i686-w64-mingw32.a
libwx_mswu_stc-3.0-i686-w64-mingw32.a
libwx_mswu_webview-3.0-i686-w64-mingw32.a
libwx_mswu_xrc-3.0-i686-w64-mingw32.a
libwxregexu-3.0-i686-w64-mingw32.a
libwxscintilla-3.0-i686-w64-mingw32.a
wx`

EDIT:

Following VZ's advise, I added `/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/bin` to my path... It compiles! 
However when run, the program does not open any window, just exits immediately. Is this still a library problem?

Comment: Have you copied dll's to the directory where a.exe is, or have you registered the libraries to Windows using environmental variables.

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy the required DLLs (at least `libstdc++-6.dll` and `libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll`) from `/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/bin` to a directory in your `PATH` or the application directory (or add this directory itself to your `PATH`, of course).

You can use `cygcheck` or (native) [dependency walker](http://dependencywalker.com/) tool to find which DLL is actually missing.